# SAP ABAP Select Query

Tags: abap

I am working through an SAP textbook to learn more about the systems and how to interact with them for work. I am very new to SAP and I don't really understand this question. Could someone please explain and help me understand what is going on here?

[image: ABAP Programming Question]

Comment: If you want a personalized answer, you have to explain what is your current knowledge and what you don't understand.

Comment: There are 2 kind of tables in SAP: Tables on the database (use SQL `SELECT` to read them) and so called "internal tables" which are basically ABAP arrays. The task is to read data from a database table and write them into an internal table. That's what `SELECT ... FROM databaseTableName INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_internal_table_name.` does.

Comment: I corrected the image: the records of the TextTable were below ValueTable.

Answer (score 0):

Some rows in `valueTable` have corresponding rows in `textTable` with language `EN`, for example ID `1`, while others have not, for example ID `2`.

You are asked to write a `SELECT` statement that joins the two tables such that only the values with English text are selected, i.e. this should be the result:

```
id | value1 | value2 | text
---| ------ | ------ | ------
 1 |    A   |   11   | Foobar
 3 |    C   |   13   | bar
```

The question can be answered with basic understanding of SQL, esp. JOINs, and does not require specific ABAP know how.